# Understanding the solution to LeetCode question 1038 - Convert BST to greater tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, binary-search-tree

In the solution I found for LeetCode question 1038, the code looks like this:

```
const bstToGst = (root) => {
    function go(root, sum) {
        if (!root) return sum;
        root.val += go(root.right, sum);
        return go(root.left, root.val);
    }
    
    go(root, 0);
    return root;
};
```

I understand the purpose of the lines `if (!root) return sum` and `root.val += go(root.right, sum)`, but I'm having trouble understanding the reason for the `return go(root.left, root.val)` statement. Can someone explain what this code is doing in more detail?

By the way, as example root you can use (if you want to explain with an example):

```
      4
    /   \
  1       6
 / \     / \
0   2   5   7
     \       \
      3       8
```

Answer (score 2):

The return `go(root.left, root.val);` statement is used to continue the traversal to theleft child of the current node, passing the updated value of the current node as the new sum. This is based on the property of the binary search tree where **all nodes in the left subtree are less than or equal to the current node**. Therefore, this sum will be added to all the nodes in the left subtree. This process continues recursively until all nodes in the tree are updated.

The solution basically uses the properties of Binary Search Tree and in-order traversal (right-root-left order in this case) to solve the problem efficiently in a single pass.

Comment: that part i understand, but why do we have to return it?

Comment: If you dont put return, the updated sum from the left subtree would not be passed back up to the parent nodes. This will likely give you incorrect values for the parent node